# Excess symbol after reading a file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run a command after reading a file.

when I use `$hostname` in the command I see

```
ssh machine? ps auxw -U myname 2>&1
```

So I have a superfluous `?` there.

My host file consists of:

```
machine01
machine02
```

It is without any excess spaces and I have only pressed `Enter`.

Please, check my example out:

```
sub CheckHosts {

    my $programname   = $_[0];
    my $HostsFileName = $ENV{'HOST_FILE'};

    open my $CFILE_HANDLE, "< $HostsFileName" or die "Error: open file $HostsFileName--$!\n";

    while ( $hostname = <$CFILE_HANDLE> ) {

        print $hostname;    # Clear output without ?

        &FindRunning( $programname, $hostname );    #Give my args in func
    }
}
```

Next:

```
sub FindRunning {

    my $programname = $_[0];
    my $hostname    = $_[1];

    print $hostname;    # Debug and get clear output without ?

    my $logname = $ENV{'USER'};
    my $rc = open PSFD, "ssh $hostname ps auxw -U $logname 2>&1 |";
}
```

How can I understand where the `?` comes from?

The process hangs on a machine, where I start to run the script. Then I use:

```
$ps ax
```

And see the line contains

```
sh -c ssh machine01? ps auxw -U user 2>&1`
```

How should I check this line, and why does an excess symbol appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading data from a file handle using `<>`, Perl splits the file into lines. What Perl thinks of as a line ending is the contents of the `$/` special variable. This value is **not** removed from the end of the line.

You can use the `chomp()` function to remove the end of line marker, if it exists, from the end of a line. So change

```
while ($hostname = <$CFILE_HANDLE>) {
    print $hostname;          #Here I debug and get clear output without ?
    &FindRunning($programname, $hostname); #Give my args in func
}
```

to this

```
while ($hostname = <$CFILE_HANDLE>) {
    print $hostname;          #Here I debug and get clear output without ?
    chomp $hostname;
    &FindRunning($programname, $hostname); #Give my args in func
}
```

The `print` works because it's printing `machine01` followed by a new line character, which moves the next entry from your file onto the next line

Comment: You're suggesting that a superfluous newline is represented by a question mark in the OP's diagnostic? It may be useful to say so.

Comment: Please discourage calling Perl subroutines with an ampersand `&`.

Comment: @JGNI          Thank you for answer. It helped me to decide the problem.